# Sum multi-index database files

Tags: python, database, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to do some operations on pandas. I have a list of countries and for each country and each year I have some data on the number of immigrants from another country. For example, `AUS 2000 AFG 11160.0` means there were 11116 people from Afganishtan in Australia in the year 2000.

I am intending to group immigrants by continents so, the expected result would be `AUS 2000 Europeans 20000; Asians 16.000; Africans 3000...` and so on. How can I do this?

```
                Foreigners   
COU Year CO2                  
AUS 2000 AFG     11160.0 
         AGO       410.0  
         ALB      1530.0  
         AND        10.0  
         ARE      1390.0  
         ARG     11820.0  
         ARM       990.0  
AUS 2001 AFG
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your dataframe has a multiindex of 'COU','Year','CO2', then you can use:

```
df.sum(level=[0,1])
```

Output:

```
          Foreigners
COU Year            
AUS 2000     27310.0
    2001         1.0
```

Or if you just want to sum on 'COU' and not year:

```
df.sum(level=0)
```

Output:

```
     Foreigners
COU            
AUS     27311.0
```

Comment: Can I filter what gets summed? For example, sum only AFG and AGO but not the rest

Comment: @Zanzag Yes, use `query`.         `df.query('CO2 == "AFG"').sum(level=0)` or to do multiple `df.query('CO2 in ["AFG","AGO"]').sum(level=0)`